# Can we Combine two convergent infinite series as follows

Tags: real-analysis

Given two infinite series $S_0 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(x, n)^{p}}$ and $S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F'(x, n)^{p}}$.

Let both of these series be 'convergent' to the same real value $K$ for some values of $x$.

Assuming for $x = x_0$ this is the case. Thus,

$S_0 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(x_0, n)^{p}} = K$

$S_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F'(x_0, n)^{p}} = K$

Now, can we claim that for new series used by combining the corresponding terms of $S_0$ and $S_1$ are also convergent, i.e.:

$S_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{F(x_0, n)^{p}}) - (\frac{1}{F'(x_0, n)^{p}}) = 0$

$S_3 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{F(x_0, n)^{p}}) + (\frac{1}{F'(x_0, n)^{p}}) = 2K$

I assume this is true, but I am not certain.

Comment: If $S_n \to S $ and $T_n \to T$ then $S_n - T_n \to S -T$. Letting these denote your partial sum sequences we see its OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since your $x_0$ is fixed anyway we can just use the standard rule of adding two convergent series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + b_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I assume by extension its also true for multiplying and division too? And also were $x$ is a complex number too ?

Comment: For division you'd need that the divisor doesn't converge to $0$. It also works for complex number. The proofs of these facts are pretty standard and shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: Thanks again. I am just beginning in analysis as a self-interest. my background is CS.